# How to Add a Custom Class to WordPress Images

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I want to add classes "overlay ratio ratio-landscape" next to "wp-block-image" and "overlay-media" next to "aligncenter size-large is-resized". Also, consider that "aligncenter size-large is-resized" these tags not used for all images.

What is now:

```
        <div class="wp-block-image">
        <figure class="aligncenter size-large is-resized">
```

What I want:

```
        <div class="wp-block-image overlay ratio ratio-landscape">
        <figure class="aligncenter size-large is-resized overlay-media">
```